# imagemagick "CONVERT" command finer points under Ubuntu 10.4

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, imagemagick

I'm struggling a little with the command line running imagemagick.

I need to convert many `.jpg` files to many `PDF` files. Each `PDF` has one jpg contained inside. I fount lots of tutorials on how to convert many `jpg` to one `PDF`, but this is not what I need.

Anywho, I would not mind paying a small bounty for a correct solution that I could handle.

Comment: You don't need a bounty, but you'd be better off explaining what your ultimate goal is, as there isn't enough detail to give a good answer. For example, do you wish to have these printed? Do you need to send them to someone or something that can't cope with a jpg. Do you wish to embed them in something else? There are answers for all of these, easy ones, but I'd rather give the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's tripping you up, but one way is to figure out how to convert one jpg to one pdf, then wrap that command in a bash for loop.

Convert one file

```
convert [convert options] file.jpg file.pdf
```

Put it in a loop, with quoting to handle filenames with spaces. The ${f$.jpg}.pdf construct replaces the .jpg extension with .pdf. Here's a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to convert all jpg files in current directory
# to pdf files
# Edit the convert line to include convert options ahead of "$f"

for f in *.jpg
do
convert "$f" "${f%.jpg}.pdf"
done
```

Put the script in the directory with the jpg files, make the script executable and run it with the command ./scriptname.

Comment: to W_Whalley

This is what I needed.  I was already able to CONVERT one file at a time.  I could not figure out the syntax for the loop.

I wonder if would be ironic to label myself a "Noob" on a forum called "SUPERUSER"?

Anyway, thanks for the quick response, it is exactly what I needed.

send me your paypal, and I'd be happy to drop you 10$us.(public---toddheffley.com)


todd

Comment: Worked great. todd

Comment: No need for cash. Glad to help. If you accept the answer, that's thanks enough.

Comment: @Todd: why didn't you upvote the answer? (I did now. You should too.)

Answer (score 2):

For processing many images, ImageMagick provides the command [mogrify](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/mogrify.html) which would be invoked like this:

```
 mogrify -format pdf *.jpg
```

To output in another directory, you can add the `-path` switch.

(I see that this particular problem is already solved, but happened upon the question and thought I'd add this for future reference).